# Eclipse "Duplicate Location" while install new Sequoyah plugin?

Tags: installation, plugins, eclipse, android

When I am trying to install [Sequoyah](http://download.eclipse.org/sequoyah/updates/2.0/) in Eclipse from **Help -> Install New Software** , either through online installation or using downloaded local site archive it gives error **Duplicate Location**.

Or even first time when I select the downloaded archived file it does not show the files rather check box with **There are no categorized items**

please help. I even tried to delete Eclipse and unpack and did all this again but same problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that the location you are trying to add exists already.

Please see this question on Stack Overflow for how you can fix this: [Eclipse “Duplicate Location” while install new Sequoyah plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920875/eclipse-duplicate-location-while-install-new-sequoyah-plugin)